# Multiple Query results in single table

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Albums 
from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Albums'
```

It returns:

```
Albums
$660.80
```

Is there a way for me to run multiple queries in one query and return in a single table?  For example:

```
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Albums from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Albums'
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Prints from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Prints'
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Frames from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Frames'


Albums  |  $660.80
Prints  |  $123.00
Frames  |  $67.00
```

======
Looks Like the concensus is to use a union
The results are not quite formatted as I would like, it returns

```
Albums
660.80
123.00
67.00
```

Comment: Somehow the consensus is UNION but the right answer is GROUP BY

Comment: Right, since there is an aggregate involved, the `UNION ALL` versions will perform three scans (or range scans disguised as index seeks), and the `UNION` versions may add a wasteful distinct sort. The `GROUP BY` solution is what you should use because (a) it's much simpler and not redundant and (b) it is almost guaranteed to perform better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a `GROUP BY`:

```
select Category, sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Total from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category IN ('Albums', 'Prints', 'Frames')
GROUP BY Category
```

Or if you want the results in multiple *columns*:

```
select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category ='Albums' THEN QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE ELSE 0 END) as Albums END
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category ='Prints' THEN QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE ELSE 0 END) as Prints END
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category ='Frames' THEN QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE ELSE 0 END) as Frames END
FROM inventoryinfo
WHERE Category IN ('Albums', 'Prints', 'Frames')
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: +1 for realizing this can easily be done in a single query with no  UNION

Comment: +1 for using a WHERE instead of a series of UNIONs. All other answers should be ignored.

Comment: @Declan_K on the bright side, there are a lot of candidates for the Peer Pressure badge :D

Comment: Haha, too simple!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could uses a [Union](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to do this. Keep in mind that each select must return the same amount of columns if you later decide to add extra columns to your results.

```
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Albums, 'Albums' as Type from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Albums'
UNION ALL
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Prints ,'Prints' as Type from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Prints'
UNION ALL
select sum(QTYINSTOCK * AVGPRICE) as Frames,'Frames' as Type from inventoryinfo
WHERE Category = 'Frames'
```

Comment: This is close, it returns in this format:

Albums<br>
660.80<br>
123.00<br>
67.00

Comment: I would use the solution provided by D Stanley. It is much simpler and not as redundant as using the union

Answer (score -1):

The union operator:

```
select "ten", 10
union
select "twenty", 20
union
select "thirty", 30
```

produces

```
ten    | 10
twenty | 20
thirty | 30
```